# Samba Permissions Issue

Tags: permissions, samba

I have samba services (v 4.3.9) set up on a development web server.  For simplicity sake, I have a folder "/samba/billfolder" that requires access from the web service AND my samba users.  When a samba user creates a file or folder, the permissions are not properly set and the web service cannot access the file / folder.  I need a folder that I can create folders and files that will give full permissions to both groups

My smb.conf look like this:

```
[global]
workgroup = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = TestServer
security = user
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[Billing]
path=/samba/billfolder
valid users = @alfdevelopers, @www-data
guest ok = no
writeable = yes
browsable = yes
create mask = 0664
force directory mode = 2775
```

Can someone please offer some suggestions on how to properly do this. The client machine is LinuxMint and the fstab  entry looks like this:

```
//192.168.1.200/Billing /mnt/Billing cifs user=myuser,password=mypassword,rw,iocharset=utf8 0   0
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your samba configuration seems correct. File permissions, group permission from the linux filesystem are checked and applied after the inital samba configuration stage.

Create a common group having users from @alpha-developers & www-data say for example **@developerswebservices**. You can easily add the necessary users to the group using /etc/group file.

```
    developerswebservices:x:xx: user1,user2,www-data
```

Put users from both the groups as shown above.Go to the working directory of the share i.e Billing

Force the newly created file inside to belong to the group of the parent, i.e Billing,

```
    $sudo chgrp -R developerswebservices Billing
    $sudo chmod -R g+s Billing
```

You can change the permission create mask with the necessary mask bits using the **umask** command.

```
    test@linuxserver:/$umask 0007
```

This wil give permission to newly created file to the user test as rw-rw--- for the user test.

Umask allows you to set the default permission bits for a file/directory 
creation for a user.

To customize the umask for all users specify the umask bits in the /etc/login.defs file.

Hope this helps ! Thanks.